# How do I prove convergence from multiple dependent sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do I prove that $a_n$ and $b_n$ converges if and only if
$a_n - b_n$ and $a_n + b_n$ converges?

Comment: The first step is trying. Have you? Is there one of the two directions that seems easier to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

($\Rightarrow$). Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be two convergent sequences. Then, $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = L$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n = M$. Now consider the sequence $c_n = a_n + b_n$. Then, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = \lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n + b_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n + \lim_{n \to \infty}b_n = L + M,$$ hence $c_n$ converges. Can you prove the other case yourself?

($\Leftarrow$). Given is that the sequences $a_n+b_n$ and $a_n-b_n$ converge. Then, \begin{align}
 \lim_{n \to \infty}a_n & = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2}(2a_n) \\
& = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2}(a_n + b_n + a_n - b_n) \\ 
& = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2}(a_n + b_n) + \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2} (a_n - b_n) \\
& = \frac{1}{2}\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n + b_n) + \frac{1}{2}\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n - b_n) \\ & = \frac{1}{2}(L_1 + L_2), \end{align} so $a_n$ converges. Can you do the proof for $b_n$ yourself?

Comment: As writing goes, writing $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ *presupposes* that the limit exists -- which you cannot in $\Leftarrow$.

Comment: If thats the case I could not have started out with $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n$ at $\Rightarrow$ either right?

Comment: Indeed. ${}{}{}$

Comment: For "$\Rightarrow$" $a_n-b_n$; is it as easy as $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = \lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n - b_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n - \lim_{n \to \infty}b_n = L - M,$ or am I mistaken here?

Comment: you're right.   $\phantom{}$